# Как записать wchar_t в файл?

Tags: c++, g++

Вывод в терминал я понял как делать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::vector<wchar_t> mas(10);
mas.push_back('Q');
mas.push_back('W');
mas.push_back('E');

for (int i = 0; i < mas.size(); i++){

    wcout << mas[i];
}
cout << endl;

}
```

Все работает.
Вопрос как мне тоже самое записать в файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iterator>     
#include <vector>       
#include <algorithm>    
#include <fstream>      


int main()
{
    std::vector<wchar_t> mas;
    mas.push_back('Q');
    mas.push_back('W');
    mas.push_back('E');

    std::wofstream os("text.txt");

    std::ostream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t> it(os, L"\n");
    std::copy(mas.cbegin(), mas.cend(), it);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться. Сложная конструкция.